# how to autofill a basic auth prompts through a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, http, basic-authentication

[image]

I saw the chrome extension bitwarden can autofill a basic auth prompt,

but I have no idea how it did this.

Thank you.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/371918

Comment: "_I saw the chrome extension bitwarden can autofill a basic auth prompt_": What exactly do you mean? Did it inject text into the native prompt dialog and submit it? If so, was it running in a native app that coordinated with the extension?

Comment: @jsejcksn It didn't inject text into the native prompt dialog which is impossible. but it actually fulfill the authorization request. Do you know how it works?

Comment: @JamesRaynor Understood. Although I haven't reviewed the source, I'm almost certain that it's based on request/response headers, and these are good places to start studying: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication, https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/webRequest/

Comment: @jsejcksn Thank you! it works, really appreciated!